What is the default font of report documentclass?
I searched everywhere but I could not find this information.
I'm trying to find the default font which is automatically being used by using:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left={0.5in}, right={0.5in}, top={0.5in}, bottom={0.5in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Regular} % This line does not work
\newfontfamily{\trajan}[UprightFont=Trajan Pro Regular, BoldFont=Trajan Pro Bold]{Trajan Pro}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \LARGE\textbf{Title here:}
    \end{center}
I would like to know what font is this
    \begin{center}
            \noindent\fontsize{18pt}{18pt}{\trajan «Trajan horse being used here»}
    \end{center}
\end{document}

If I run pdffonts main.pdf I get:
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
YJZMGS+LMRoman12-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     14  0
ITXLYK+LMRoman12-Bold                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     17  0
VLUEEO+LMRoman12-Italic              CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     18  0
RYIVUX+TrajanPro-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     19  0

It is correct that I use TrajanPro, but what I would like to know the default font used so that I can use it (LMRoman12) inside \setmainfont{}, but currently \setmainfont{LMRoman12} does not work..

It's Computer Modern.

First of all note, that without any document body, no fonts are used. If you add a body, it depends on the body and the engine. For example PDFLaTeX would use Computer Modern (usually the Type 1 version, e.g., cmr12.pfb), but LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX would use the OTF font Latin Modern Regular.

Computer Modern is a legacy font. If you want to know the fonts used by a document, see either the document properties in your PDF viewer or use a tool like pdffonts.

This question is similar to: How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Without a minimal working example nobody can tell you, why Trajan Pro Regular is used. An absolute minimal document with your code snippet: \documentclass[12pt]{report} \begin{document} Test \end{document}, would not use it. And if you would minimize your document, you would find out yourself, which package or code is responsible for the usage of that font.

Latin Modern Regular is the default (lmroman12-regular.otf after loading fontspec and when using 12pt). So you don't need to use, e.g., \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} to use it, but remove the cause of using another font. With the current shown code it is not clear, where Trajan Pro is loaded. So it is not clear, whether this is your main font or another font used somewhere else. If you want a real answer, you need to show a real minimal working example (see the link above). And you should also make clear, what should be changed.

Thanks all. I have updated the question again.

Thanks @cabohah. The answer is as you mentioned \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}. This is what I wanted to know..

You ask for the default font in report but then load fontspec which change sthat, do you want the default for book or the default for fontspec ?

@ellat No, the answer is: If you want the default, don't change it. \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} is not needed (and could also change more than wanted, depending on the options used when loading fontspec).

unrelated to fonts but Trajan refers to an emperor of that name, Trojan refers to the city of Troy where they had a horse

Off-topic: left={0.5in}, right={0.5in}, top={0.5in}, bottom={0.5in} may be expressed more succinctly as margin=0.5in.

@DavidCarlisle Trajan surely had a horse too

The report class has no “default font”. Several classes don't, actually.
If the class (or some package you load) doesn't choose a main document font, you get the LaTeX default, which depends on the engine

pdflatex: Computer Modern (OT1 encoding) or European Modern (T1 encoding);

xelatex and lualatex: Latin Modern Roman;

platex and uplatex: the same as pdflatex.


To be precise, neither xelatex nor lualatex set a default font at the beginning of a job; for technical reasons this is done later.
If you want to use Latin Modern Roman as the main font with xelatex or lualatex, you just have to do nothing at all. You may want to select it explicitly in order to change font features by
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}


It is still unclear, what you are trying, because you don't need any \setmainfont{…} to have get the default font or to get any of the Latin Modern families like Latin Modern Roman. So maybe your question is a XY problem.
However, you are explicitly loading Trajan Pro:
\newfontfamily{\trajan}[UprightFont=Trajan Pro Regular, BoldFont=Trajan Pro Bold]{Trajan Pro}

as new font command \trajan. And you are using it here:
{\trajan «Trajan horse being used here»

But your main font is not changed. So you are still using Latin Modern as main font.
If you don't want to use Trajan Pro remove the loading of the font or at least the usage:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left={0.5in}, right={0.5in}, top={0.5in}, bottom={0.5in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily{\trajan}[UprightFont=Trajan Pro Regular, BoldFont=Trajan Pro Bold]{Trajan Pro}% Wouldn't matter, if is is not used anywhere.

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \LARGE\textbf{Title here:} % This is already Latin Modern Roman
    \end{center}
I would like to know what font is this % This is already Latin Modern Roman
    \begin{center}
            \noindent\fontsize{18pt}{23pt}\selectfont «Latin Modern Regular horse being used here»
    \end{center}
\end{document}

  \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}

But if you really want a second Latin Modern Roman, you could do the following nonsense:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left={0.5in}, right={0.5in}, top={0.5in}, bottom={0.5in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\nottrajan}{Latin Modern Roman}% doesn't really make sense and could be replaced by `\newcommand{\nottrajan}{\normalfont}`.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
            \LARGE\textbf{Title here:}
    \end{center}
I would like to know what font is this
    \begin{center}
            \noindent\fontsize{18pt}{23pt}\nottrajan «Not Trajan horse being used here»
    \end{center}
\end{document}

  \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}

BTW: \fontsize{18pt}{18pt} is not recommended, because it would typeset without base line distance. Better use, e.g., \Large or \fontsize{18pt}{23pt} or similar (as shown in my example).
